# Are database records actually "structures" like those in C?

Tags: database, data-structures

A structure can store different datatypes (and data) under one heading, and that is exactly what a record in a database is.

Questions:

1. Is every record a structure?
2. Is a table a template for a structure?
3. If so, a structure is identified by a variable name. What is used to identify a record structure in a DB?
4. If databases are optimized to not use structures, then how are records implemented?

Comment: 1) Just mentioning C does not rectify the tag. 2) What did you find out yourself? What did you try? What is your **specific** problem? 3) There is no single "database" type.

Comment: 1) Nope, it isn't a structure (not a C-like structure anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Database records are similar to C structures in that they support named fields with specified types. The similarity probably ends there. In general, don't think of a record as a structure in C. Some fundamental differences come to mind:

- Databases don't support (generally) arrays.
- Databases don't support (directly) pointers.
- Databases don't support nesting of structures.
- Databases don't require that data be stored consecutively or be aligned.
- Databases columns have nullable attributes, default values, and can enforce constraints.

I'm sure there are other differences as well.

Even more important, database records are stored on *data pages*, which are managed by a page management system and might be in memory or on disk. Databases also enforce ACID properties and ensure transactional consistency.

You may want to investigate whatever database you are using and learn how it stores data.

Comment: _some_ databases support arrays, though :)